# Oracle SQL - how to NOT SHOW athlete name that apears only once

Tags: sql, oracle

created a view called winners, it contains the columns: athlete_name,year,medal_won
its basicly athletes that won olympic medal and the year, 
it look like that,

data base is in live sql: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000:0

```
select distinct year,athlete_name,medal
from olym.olym_medals
join olym.olym_athlete_games on olym_athlete_games.id = olym_medals.athlete_game_id
join olym.olym_nations on olym_nations.id = olym_athlete_games.nation_id
join olym.olym_games on olym_games.id = Olym_athlete_games.game_id 
join olym.olym_athletes on olym_athletes.id = olym_athlete_games.athlete_id
order by  athlete_name
```

as you can see some name show only once and some names are showing more than once, i want to get rid off all lines of those who show ONLY ONCE, please help me.
thank you!

Comment: Please provide your data and query as tabular text rather than images, that we can't copy/paste.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables (as text, not images) and DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data so that people who want to help you have a script that they can copy/paste and run and do not have to reverse engineer your code from an image.

Comment: fixed it now, you have the database and my code

Comment: Your link does not work; it goes to the LiveSQL homepage and when you sign in then the worksheet is empty.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understand your problem, must group your data,

```
  select year,athlete_name,medal, count(*) "number of Medals" 
  from olym.olym_medals
  join olym.olym_athlete_games on olym_athlete_games.id = olym_medals.athlete_game_id
 join olym.olym_nations on olym_nations.id = olym_athlete_games.nation_id
 join olym.olym_games on olym_games.id = Olym_athlete_games.game_id 
 join olym.olym_athletes on olym_athletes.id = olym_athlete_games.athlete_id
 group by year,athlete_name,medal;
```

Comment: you counted how many time each medal appeared, i want to count how many time each athlete name_appears, and get rid off those who show only once

Comment: So remove medal from group by part

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select og.year, oa.athlete_name, om.medal, count(*) over(partition by oa.id) cnt
    from olym.olym_medals om
    join olym.olym_athlete_games oag on oag.id = om.athlete_game_id
    join olym.olym_nations ona       on ona.id = oag.nation_id
    join olym.olym_games og          on og.id = oag.game_id 
    join olym.olym_athletes oa on    oa.id = oag.athlete_id
) t
where cnt > 1
order by  athlete_name
```

Notes:

- I am unsure why you were using `distinct` in the first place, so I removed it (I suspect it is actually not needed)
- I added table aliases to shorten the query, and prefixed the columns in the `select` clause with the table they belong to (you might want to review that) - these are best practices when dealing with multi-table queries

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`:

```sql
SELECT year,
       athlete_name,
       medal
FROM   olym.olym_medals
       INNER JOIN olym.olym_athlete_games
       ON olym_athlete_games.id = olym_medals.athlete_game_id
       INNER JOIN olym.olym_nations
       ON olym_nations.id = olym_athlete_games.nation_id
       INNER JOIN olym.olym_games
       ON olym_games.id = Olym_athlete_games.game_id 
       INNER JOIN olym.olym_athletes
       ON olym_athletes.id = olym_athlete_games.athlete_id
GROUP BY
       year,
       athlete_name,
       medal
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY  athlete_name
```